# How to convert string to integer [Laravel - MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I use https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb query builder for mongodb. Now I have problem. In my collection I have key 'storage' which value can be T(string) or number(also in string format).

I tried with whereRaw but that's not help.

```
$query->where('storage', '>=', 9);
```

I don't know how to create query, because if I compare integer and string (from collection) I can't get right value.

Comment: you must normalize the field data type first, that's the right way to go. Otherwise, you'll get a partial collection  (depend on what storage value data type is...)

Comment: @felipsmartins storage value data type is string, but I want to check storage >= 9

Comment: @felipsmartins also, storage can be string T and integer (1,2,3,4)

Comment: if `storage` field is `9` (an int), so: `$query->where('storage', '>=', 9)`; if `storage` field is `"9"` (numeric string), so: `$query->where('storage', '>=', "9")`; if `storage` field is `"T"` (string), so: `$query->where('storage', '>=', "T")`; Of course, `>=` in the two last cases does not makes sense. That is why I said you must normalize storage field to integer/number.